# Copy a file included with an Adobe Air application out of the Application so that it can be modified

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air, flex4

Is it possible to provide an existing SQLite file with an Air installer, and have the Air application copy it out to local storage upon first execution so that it can be modified?

Or do I need to take my pre-made db and recreate it on the fly with Air on execution (store all the queries required to create the tables/data in the application)?

Comment: I don't have personal experience, but.. 
I was under the impression that most people recreate the DB on the fly during the initial application's execution.  I would have assumed that reading/writing to a SQLLite database inside the app install directory would have worked, but it's a tricky issue [from my lack of experience]

Comment: I was pretty sure as far as the fact that Air applications are distributed and executed by comparing certificates that any modification to the data within the application (particularly OS X app bundles) would be a no no. Will probably just recreate unless someone comes along with a first hand accounting.

Comment: Ah crap, but I want image blob data in said database, recreating that should be just as hard as getting the SQLite db out of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have a book that tells me what to do. If you package files alongside your application, the application is installed into a folder or contains a folder (OS X? it's still really unclear how this works cross platform, whether the db goes into the app bundle or not), and that is what File.applicationDirectory references, and you can then copy right from it.

Adobe Air 1.5 Cookbook Recipe 10.12 :)